# Sub file references main file, but references do not appear when compiling main file

Tags: cross-referencing, external-files, standalone, xr

I am trying to write a large document, and for the sake of organized editing, it makes sense to have each chapter as a standalone document. I am using the `standalone` package to accomplish this. I have references in the main document that need to be used in subdocuments, and I am trying to use the `xr` package to accomplish this. However, I have run into the following problem.

A minimal working example is as follows. We have a primary file `main.tex`, and a secondary file `sub/sub.tex` in a subfolder. The `main.tex` file reads:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}
\usepackage{xr}

\begin{document}
    \section{Test}\label{test}
    \input{sub/sub}

\end{document}
```

and the `sub/sub.tex` file reads

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,class=article, crop=false]{standalone}

\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument[main-]{../main}

\begin{document}
    Referencing the main section: \ref{main-test}
\end{document}
```

When I compile `sub/sub.tex`, it works as expected:
[image: Correct output of sub/sub.tex]

However, when I compile `main.tex`, the reference cannot be found:
[image: Incorrect output of main.tex]

How can I get the subfile to reference the main file in such a way that the reference compiles correctly in the main file?